# How to release TAO module resources?

Tags: ace-tao

TAO client module throws an exception when closed:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
TAO_ORB_Core::resource_factory(...)-> was 0xDDDDDDDD.
In TAO library Leader_Follower.cpp 51 line  "this->orb_core_->resource_factory ()->reclaim_reactor (this->reactor_);"

When finished, I call: orb->shutdown();

How to free resources properly?

I tried to call: orb->destroy();
Same result